# GCD and Threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I want to understand something about GCD and Threads.

I have a for loop in my view controller which asks my model to do some async network request.

So if the loop runs 5 times, the model sends out 5 network requests.

Is it correct to state that 5 threads have been created by my model considering the fact that I'm using NSURLConnection's sendAsyncRequest and the completion handlers will be called on an additional 5 threads ?

Now, If I ask my view controller to execute this for loop on a different thread and in every iteration of the loop, the call to the model should be dependent on the previous iteration, would I be creating an "Inception" of threads here ?

Basically, I want the subsequent async requests to my server only if the previous thread has completed entirely (By entirely I mean all of its sub threads should have finished executing too.)

I can't even frame the question properly because I'm massively confused myself.
But if anybody could help with anything, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not correct to state that five threads have been created in the general case.

There is no one-to-one mapping between threads and blocks. GCD is an implementation of thread pooling.

A certain number of threads are created according to the optimal setup for that device — the cost of creating and maintaing threads under that release of the OS, the number of processor cores available, the number of threads it already has but which are presently blocked and any other factors Apple cares to factor in may all be relevant.

GCD will then spread your blocks over those threads. Or it may create new threads. But it won't necessarily.

Beyond that queues are just ways of establishing the sequencing between blocks. A serial dispatch queue does not necessarily own its own thread. All concurrent dispatch queues do not necessarily own their own threads. But there's no reason to believe that any set of queues shares any threads.

The exact means of picking threads for blocks has changed between versions of the OS. E.g. iOS 4 was highly profligate in thread creation, in a way that iOS 5+ definitely haven't been.

GCD will just try to do whatever is best in the circumstances. Don't waste your time trying to second guess it.

Answer (score 1):

"Basically, I want the subsequent async requests to my server only if the previous thread has completed entirely (By entirely I mean all of its sub threads should have finished executing too.)"

Only focusing on the above statement to avoid confusion. Simple solution would be create a queue. feed the queue with 5 loops. Each loop will be making network request synchronously(you can use **sendSynchronousRequest:** method available in NSURLConnection), performing the operations after request completion and then start the next loop. queue following FIFO will execute the your requests subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

GCD : Think of this as a simple queue that can accept tasks. Tasks are blocks of your code. You can put in as many tasks as you want in a queue (permitting system limits). Queues come in different flavors. Concurrent vs Serial. Main vs Global. High Priority vs Low Priority. A queue is not a thread.

Thread : It is a single line of execution of code in sequence. You can have multiple threads working on your code at the same time. A thread is not a queue.

Once you separate the 2 entities things start become clear.

GCD basically uses the threads in the process to work on tasks. In a serial queue everything is processed in sequence. So you don't need to have synchronization mechanisms in your code, the very nature of serial queue ensures synchronization. If this is a concurrent queue (i.e. 2 or more tasks being processed at the same time, then you need to ensure critical sections of your code are protected with synchronization).

Here is how you queue work to be done.

```
dispatch_async(_yourDispatchQueue, ^() {
    NSLog (@"work queued");
});
```

The above NSLog will now get executed in a background thread in a near future time, but in a background thread.

If you notice when we put a request in we use dispatch_async. The other variation is dispatch_sync. The different between the 2 is after you put the request in the queue, the async variation will move on. The sync variation will not !!

If you are going to use a GCD for NSURLConnection you need to be careful on which thread you start the connection. Here is a SO link for more info. [GCD with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071978/gcd-with-nsurlconnection/13075902#comment38557809_13075902)